# Why to use getCacheDir() on Android

Tags: android

Android may auto-delete the files in CacheDir once the system gets low on memory. But the docs say we should not rely on the system clearing this cache, and hence write additional code for polling and deleting.

If this is the case, why should one choose `getCacheDir()` over `getFilesDir()`? Both are in-memory, and the latter offers more power to the developer in terms of what to clean up and when.

Thanks!

Comment: because you can use the "clear cache" button in system settings > apps

Comment: An other reason also if you don't need to persist anything else is that it does not require any permission from the user

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Android may auto-delete the files in CacheDir once the system gets low on memory.

Correct. Third party apps can also delete files from apps' cache directories. And, as zapl notes, the user can manually clear an app's cache from Settings.

> But the docs say we should not rely on the system clearing this cache, and hence write additional code for polling and deleting.

Also correct.

> If this is the case, why should one opt getCacheDir() over getFileDir() ?

Because the OS, third-party apps, and the user *can* clear the cache. However, just because those things *can* clear the cache does not mean that they automatically *will* clear the cache, and so you need to tidy up your cache from time to time yourself. Similarly, while your mother *can* clean your room, it is generally a good idea if you clean your room yourself, if you don't want to be hit with a broom.

> and the latter offers more power to the developer in terms of what to clean up and when...

No, it does not. `getCacheDir()` returns a `File` object. `getFilesDir()` returns a `File` object. They are equivalent in terms of "power to the developer in terms of what to clean up and when".

Comment: I didnt get _getCacheDir() returns a File object. getFilesDir() returns a File object._ Can you please explain

Comment: @raul8 They both return a `File` object so the OP seems to be mistaken that `getFilesDir()` "offers more power to the developer". They both offer the same power.

Comment: Plus one for the **"mother _can_ clean your room"** analogy.

Comment: @Commonsware if the goal is to keep cache for a long time without unnecessarily getting in radar of cache clearing 3rd party apps/ system's low memory cache blaster, should one opt for `getFilesDir()` over  `getCacheDir()` ?

Comment: @anshsachdeva: The point of a cache is to be cleared. If you do not want the cache to be cleared, then it is not a cache. Ideally, you let the cache be cleared by any possible trigger, including user action in Settings. If, for some reason, that is inappropriate, then do not use Android's cache options (`getCacheDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`), because from the OS' standpoint, what you want is not a cache.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want a memory storage that holds  a large amount of video data that gets fetched on every network call. if i play a 10 youtube videos 10 times , closing/reopening the app in between , they will all get cached and not downloaded , right ?  the downloading will be a different part, because in that case we are making a persistant file in user's memory system. I feel my definition of cache will be a storage of say 250 mb of network data combined from various watched videos, which gets cleared only if i add a new video cache in an already filled cache

Comment: @anshsachdeva: "if i play a 10 youtube videos 10 times , closing/reopening the app in between , they will all get cached and not downloaded , right ?" -- I cannot speak to YouTube's implementation. However, the details may be more complex than one might think, due to things like DRM. "I feel my definition of cache will be a storage of say 250 mb of network data combined from various watched videos, which gets cleared only if i add a new video cache in an already filled cache" -- why would you prevent the user from clearing that cache?

Comment: @CommonsWare "why would you prevent the user from clearing that cache?" I will not be preventing user from clearing their cache if i use `getFilesDir()` . However I don't want to get in radar of cache killing services , like task manager or some firewall (or device reboot?) . From the above discussion, what i get is that user can still clear all of their app memory by going into system app settings,and as long as they are not doing it, my video player will simply keep on playing from the cache. is that correct?

Comment: @anshsachdeva: "However I don't want to get in radar of cache killing services , like task manager" -- why? If the user opted into some sort of cache manager, that is the user's choice. 250MB is not a trivial amount of storage space for some users on low-end phones. "or device reboot" -- cache files survive a reboot, at least on the equipment that I have tested. "that user can still clear all of their app memory by going into system app settings" -- that deletes everything, though: SQLite, `SharedPreferences`, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand. From the above discussion, i think cache directories are a way to go, as they adhere to user's choices. Don't want to trigger google into changing file/memory rules again by showing another small exploit hehe

Answer (score 3):

`getCacheDir()` returns the path to the cache files whereas `getFilesDir()` returns the path to files created and stored in the internal storage of your app. The internal storage is persistent: it cannot be deleted by the system.

Comment: That's the question. Why shouldn't I use getFilesDir() for caching then ? How is getCacheDir() helping me ?

Comment: I see your point. I see it is a convenience cache storage location on which you can apply a logic without any risk to mess things up because it's separated from your persistent storage.